# Consulta no MySQL para retornar registros agendados para os próximos 30 dias

Tags: php, mysql, data

Tenho uma tabela chamada AGENDA, onde nela tenho os campos, ID, Local, Data. Fazer a inserção e a seleção dentro do banco de dados já consegui fazer corretamente. Mas não consigo selecionar a data por ordem crescente, mostrando os eventos que acontecerão primeiro, e queria restringir os eventos apenas nos próximos 30 dias. Tem algum comando no php/mysql para isso, ou eu teria que desenvolver uma função para isso?

Solução após respostas/comentários:

Estrutura da tabela:

**id - Auto Increment**

**data - Date**

**Local - varchar**

Código exibir.php:

```
<?php

include "configurar.inc";   

// Capturando o ano atual para quando for selecionar o mês dos eventos não aparecer de todos os anos. 

$dataatual = explode("/", date('d/m/Y'));
$anoatual = $dataatual[2];

// Supondo que quero o mês de maio (5) 

$sql = "SELECT * FROM datas WHERE MONTH(data) = 5 AND YEAR(data) = $anoatual ORDER BY data ASC";
$query = mysql_query($sql);

echo "Proximos Eventos: ";

while($linha = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
    $datasemformato = $linha['data'];

    $dataformatada = implode("/", array_reverse(explode("-", $datasemformato)));

    echo "<br>";
    echo "$dataformatada";

    // Compara data e diz se o evento é hoje.

    if(date('d/m/Y')==$dataformatada) {
        echo " -> Esse evento é hoje.!";
    }

    // Compara a data e diz se o evento é amanhã.

    if(date('d/m/Y', strtotime("+1 day"))==$dataformatada) {
        echo " -> Esse evento será amanhã.!";
    }
}
  ?>
```

Caso quiser exibir os eventos dos próximos 30 dias: `WHERE data between NOW() and DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)`

Comment: Pelo que vi já foi solucionado sua questão, mas se possível coloque a estrutura de sua tabela para futuras pesquisas de outros usuários. Poderá ajudar alguém. Eu sei que colocou os campos, mas a estrutura em si dos campos ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Para selecionar a data em ordem você deverá utilizar [ORDER BY](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_orderby.asp) na sua consulta.

Para mostrar uma data dos próximos 30 dias, você poderá utilizar o comando [DATE_ADD](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add) do mySQL e adicionar o intervalo de 1 mês ( ou de 30 dias )

A consulta deverá ficar semelhante a essa:

```
SELECT *
FROM AGENDA
WHERE data between NOW() and DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
ORDER BY data
```

Dessa forma, a consulta deverá retornar o desejado. Você poderá colocar ORDER BY data ASC/DESC de acordo com a ordenação ( crescente ou decrescente ) que deseja obter.

Comment: Cara, ordenar por data eu consegui. O que não consegui foi restringir dentro dos próximos 30 dias. Quando coloco esse trecho: WHERE data between new NOW() and DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH), dá o seguinte erro: Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in...

Comment: Opa, consegui arrumar apenas tirando o new NOW().

Comment: @JoãoNeto o "new" antes do Now() foi um erro de digitação ( tinha escrito new Date(), mas não é o correto para MySQL ). Resposta editada.

Comment: Valeu, obrigado pela atenção =)

Comment: Felipe, só mais uma dúvida, se puder editar a resposta e colocar, caso eu escolha o mês de maio, como mostrar só os registros para o mês de maio, tem como?

Comment: @JoãoNeto WHERE data ...... AND MONTH(data) = 5

Comment: Valeu bacco, deu certinho!

Answer (score 1):

Creio que isto ajude...

```
  $query = "SELECT nome, celular, profissao, cpf, rg,hora,faltou,codigo_convenio  
     FROM pacientes  
    INNER JOIN agenda  
    ON agenda.codigo_paciente=pacientes.codigo  
    WHERE (DATA = DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y-%m-%d'));";  
    $resultado = mysql_query($query,$conexao) or die(mysql_error());  


    if(mysql_num_rows($resultado)>0)  
    {  
    print "<table border='3' ALIGN='center'><FONT FACE='Arial' SIZE='10' COLOR='black'>";  
    print "<tr colspan='10' rowspan='10'><td id='celula0'>Hora</td><td id='celula1'>Paciente</td><td id='celula2'>Presente?</td><td id='celula3'>P.Saude</td><td id='celula4'>Tel</td><td id='celula2'>Histórico</td></tr>";  
    while ($info = mysql_fetch_array($resultado))  
                  {  

    print "<tr colspan='10' rowspan='10'><td id='celula0'>$info[hora]</td> <td id='celula1'>$info[nome]</td><td id='celula2'>$info[faltou]</td><td id='celula3'>$info[codigo_convenio]</td><td id='celula4'>$info[celular]</td><td id='celula4'>$info[celular]</td></tr>";  
           }  
    print "</table>";  
     }  
    else{  
    echo "Não há pacientes para hoje!";  


    }   

     ?>  

    </body>  
    </html>
```

Comment: Ao adicionar código, sempre formate-o, selecionando todo e clicando em `{}`